How and where to save topics' content
I want to create an online educational platform for chemistry. The platform will be similar to a documentation site for any technology like mui, angular or angular material. Moreover, there will be many lessons, and each lesson will have headers, paragraphs, pictures, lists, and maybe a table. Where is it better to store lesson content in the frontend or backend? If in the frontend or backend, then how? Please give me tips with examples because I am beginner to development. Frontend - angular, backend - spring boot
I saved each lesson as a page component in the frontend. and I don't think it's a better idea
